# How do you delete files older than specific date in Linux?

Tags: linux, find, delete-file

I used the below command to delete files older than a year.

```
  find /path/* -mtime +365 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

But now I want to delete all files whose modified time is older than *01 Jan 2014.* How do I do this in Linux?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can touch your timestamp as a file and use that as a reference point:

e.g. for 01-Jan-2014:

```
touch -t 201401010000 /tmp/2014-Jan-01-0000

find /path -type f ! -newer /tmp/2014-Jan-01-0000 | xargs rm -rf
```

this works because `find` has a `-newer` switch that we're using.

From `man find`:

```
-newer file
       File  was  modified  more  recently than file.  If file is a symbolic
       link and the -H option or the -L option is in effect, the modification time of the 
       file it points to is always used.
```

Comment: Thank you. 
! is as good as -not "find . -not  -newer /tmp/2014-Jan-01-0000 "

Comment: this is polluting the file system. -newer(a/b/c/m/t) timestamp can do it efficiently. please update your answer

Comment: @yoga Or just delete the file when you're done. It's literally in the "temporary files" directory

Answer (score 83):

This works for me:

```
find /path ! -newermt "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: this is very nice, I don't pollute filesystem with temp timestamp file!

Comment: For just files `find /path ! -type f -newermt "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" -delete`. It saves you from having to pipe everything through xargs, and having to handle filesnames with spaces or other disruptive characters.

Comment: For what it's worth, `-newermt` is a non-standard extension, though on Linux systems you will typically have GNU `find`. This is not portable to other platforms.

Comment: Adding -delete argument to the find command also works.

Comment: Careful with @jbo5112 's command as that will delete everything that isn't a file, the ! needs to be moved to the other side of -type f

Comment: You can use `date --date="today" "+%Y-%m-%d"` to get files older than today. Something like `--date="last friday"` works too!
`find /path ! -newermt "\`date --date="today"  "+%Y-%m-%d"\`" | xargs rm -rf`

Comment: Corrected command `find /path -type f ! -newermt "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" -delete` thanks @Shardj

Answer (score 35):

[This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33091121/10871073) pollutes the file system and `find` itself offers a "delete" option. So, we don't have to pipe the results to xargs and then issue an rm.

This answer is more efficient:

```
find /path -type f -not -newermt "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS" -delete
```

Comment: The data fmt is wrong: use      find /path -type f -not -newermt "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS" -delete

Comment: This seems to repeat [an older answer from 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45883352/874188), though the `-delete` option is an improvement.

Answer (score 7):

```
find ~ -type f ! -atime 4|xargs ls -lrt
```

This will list files accessed **older than 4 days**, searching from home directory.

Comment: Actually `! -atime 4` means "do not match any files accessed exactly 4 days ago". You'd need to use  `-atime +4` for "match file accessed more than 4 days ago". The full command would be `find ~ -type f -atime +4 | xargs ls -lrt`

Answer (score 0):

First I execute this

touch -t 202310080000 /tmp/olddate  ---> this creates a file with the specified date

find "path to which you want to apply search" -type f ! -newer /tmp/olddate -delete   -----> this deletes files from the path where you want with reference to the file created at the certain date.