# How to delete all files before 1/1/2017

Tags: linux

Please I need to find all files before 1/1/2017 and delete them on Linux platform

I have searched and found this find ./ -type f -mtime  -exec rm -rf {} \; so how to specify the above date

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091013/delete-files-older-than-specific-date-in-linux

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete files older than specific date in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091013/delete-files-older-than-specific-date-in-linux)

Comment: Too late. That was more than a year ago.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions that have been asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score -1):

I hope these commands help

```
touch -d "2010-11-21 23:59:59" /tmp/date.start;
touch -d "2010-11-23 00:00:00" /tmp/date.end;
find ./ -type f -newer /tmp/date.start ! -newer /tmp/date.end -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: nice but I have disk contains 100G files so in my case how to do so?

Comment: as far as I know if you add + instead of \; then you'll get a performance boost. That should help you with large number of files.