# delete yyyy-MM-dd folders where date string is older than X days

Tags: linux, bash, date, find

I have a directory with a bunch of folders named in `yyyy-MM-dd` format. I want to delete all the folders where the `yyyy-MM-dd` string is older than X days.

```
# ls
2018-01-01
2018-01-02
2018-01-03
...
2018-02-01
2018-03-05
...
2019-01-02
2019-01-02
```

Is it possible to find like this?

Update:

This question is not a duplicate of [Delete files older than specific date in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091013/delete-files-older-than-specific-date-in-linux) because that talks about finding files by `mtime` and I want to find by file name where the file name matches a date string. For example, the name of a directory could be `2012-01-01` but it's `mtime` could be `2018-03-11`. This is why `mtime` or any of the other date/time metadata will not work for my needs.

Comment: Did you try anything for yourself? Post those efforts into the question

Comment: I didn't because I'm not even sure where to start. I mean I know how to find files and all that, and I know about `mtime` or `ctime` but that won't work for me...

Comment: Which platform are you working on? MacOS, Windows10, Ubuntu or other Linux/Unix system?

Comment: `linux` and `bash`.

Comment: @tripleee I updated the question with details on why it is **not** a duplicate of the one you marked.

Comment: This is unlikely to be reopened until you demonstrate some coding effort of your own. Feel free to ping me for a possible reopen once you have made an [edit] to show what you have tried so far and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Having said that, we have a cubic light-year of very similar questions, so you are likely to find (or be directed to) another duplicate once we see what precisely you find challenging.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to add more detail. I haven't tried anything because I don't even know where to start. But I think one of the answers below might work so I'm going to give that a try and see.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current date in days since the UNIX epoch by

```
echo $(($(date +%s)/86400))
```

You can do the same for a string formatted the same way that you have above:

```
echo $(($(date +%s --date "2018-01-01"))/86400)
```

Then the number of days between "today" and an arbitrary date:

```
echo $(($(date +%s)/86400 - $(date +%s --date "2018-01-01")/86400))
```

Wrap it up in a loop, and you should be good to go:

```
for DIR in `ls -1`
do
    # if the directory name is parseable as a date...
    if date "$DIR" &>/dev/null
    then
        age=$(($(date +%s)/86400 - $(date +%s --date "$DIR")/86400))
        echo "$DIR is $age days old"
        # do something based on its age
        if [ $age -gt 30 ]
        then
            #rm -fr "$DIR"
            echo $DIR
        fi
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

As always mentioned, bash does not support a built-in date&time function.
Although `date` command is sometimes useful to compensate it, the command
has a lot of variations and often causes compatibiliy problems.
It is recommended to make use of other programming languages which
natively support the date&time arithmetic.
Here's an example in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import glob
import re
import datetime
import shutil
import os

retention = 100     # or whatever period you want to preserve
now = datetime.datetime.now()

for dir in glob.glob("*-*-*"):
    if re.search("^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$", dir):
        dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dir, "%Y-%m-%d")
        if ((now - dt).days > retention):
            shutil.rmtree(dir)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use python. I need to find a bash way.

Comment: Python can be called from Bash just like `date` or `awk`

Comment: Python is not on this system unfortunately. Trust me, I wish it was. I know Python very well and could have done this in minutes if I could use Python.