# How do I setup the deletion of old logs?

Tags: database, distributed-database, yugabytedb

After running yugabyte db for some time, I see that the logs are never deleted. How can I configure the server to delete old logs ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently YugabyteDB doesn't provide an automatic way to delete old logs.
You can achieve this by running a bash script in crontab that deletes old files.

Examples:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/589210/removing-files-older-than-7-days

[Delete files older than specific date in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091013/delete-files-older-than-specific-date-in-linux/56859384)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/413529/delete-files-older-than-one-year-on-linux